# How to show an array of images, without freezing the whole programm for seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, image, performance

I have the following problem:

I want to make a **little 2d-game** in **c#**.
To display a background that consists of **several images**. To make **animated gifs** possible, i used **MediaElement** objects.
I added these MediaElements to my **Canvas**.
But when i run my programm, the **performance is a disaster**. It takes almost half a minute to display the images.

I obviously need a better idea to display an array of images, without slowing down everything.

This is my Starting-Point:

```
class BackgroundMediaElement : MediaElement
{

    public BackgroundMediaElement(string imageSourcePath, int rowInCanvas, int columnInCanvas, int lengthOfSquare)
    {
        this.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        this.Source = new Uri(imageSourcePath, UriKind.Relative);

        Canvas.SetTop(this, rowInCanvas*lengthOfSquare);
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, columnInCanvas*lengthOfSquare);

        this.Play();

        this.MediaEnded += method_MediaEnded;
    }

    private void method_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MediaElement m = (MediaElement)sender;
        this.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
    }
}
```

I created more than 200 elements and added them to my Canvas.
But it even slows down with 40 elements.
One image does not even have one kByte.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: How much is "several" images?

Comment: This could be anything. A few dozen MediaElements should work, hundreds is stretching it.

Comment: A "little 2d-game" should be easily supported by WPF. Even if by "several" you mean "dozens", performance should be fine. But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to answer the question.